# Resolve javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: javascript, android, encryption

I am using the following code to decrypt a message

```
try {
            byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            // we generate a AES SecretKeySpec object which contains the secret key.
            // SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_METHOD);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKeySpec(), ips);

            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes());
            byte[] base64encodedSecretData = Base64.encodeBase64(cipherText);
            String secretString = new String(base64encodedSecretData);
            return secretString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Encryption error for " + textToEncrypt, e);
        }
        return "";
```

this is my getSecretKeySpec()

```
public static Key getSecretKeySpec() {

        if (SECRET_KEY == null) {
            byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];

            // byte[] bytes = Globals.APPLICATION.APP_KEY.getBytes();
            byte[] bytes = Globals.context.getPackageName().getBytes();
            if (bytes.length > 16) {
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    keyBytes[j] = bytes[i];
                    j++;
                    if (j > 7)
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                    keyBytes[i] = 'q';

                int j = 0;
                for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    keyBytes[j] = bytes[i];
                }
            }

            SECRET_KEY = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        }
        return SECRET_KEY;
    }
```

I searched a lot in SO and others but wasnt able to resolve this.Can anyone point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

***Replace this***

```
byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

***WITH***

```
 byte[] iv = { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0','0' };
```